# Magento 2 - use email as coupon code

Tags: magento2

In my current webstore created in OpenCart, the customers email is the coupon code, so when a customer subscribes to our newsletter for a 5% discount they can use their email at the checkout page, and 5% of the order amount will automatically be subtracted.

Is it possible to have a system like this in Magento 2? I can see that coupon codes and price rules are a standard functionality in Magento 2, but this doesn't seem to be a part of it.

Thanks.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: some paid modules are there you may purchase 
https://www.mageants.com/newsletter-popup-extension-for-magento-2.html
And this one 
http://www.magetrend.com/magento-2-newsletter-popup-extension

Comment: I have created my own popup which is a MailChimp form, I just need Magento to recognize which email is entered in the checkout form and subtract 5% from the cart.

Comment: for that you can create one shopping cart rule in magento2  and generate  coupon code like this tutorial https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-create-a-cart-price-rule-in-magento-2.html

after that you need to override the controller where magento subscribes user so over ther in email code you need to pass your coupon code to send them in the email.

Comment: I don't want a coupon code. The email should be the coupon code, when a user checks out using an email that are subscribed to our newsletter, then 5% should be subtracted from their order. The email address is the coupon code, the user only needs to put in their email in the "email address" field at the checkout form. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement some custom logic for **checkout/cart/couponPost** request to achieve that, if using email as coupon is a requirement

Take a look at **vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/CouponPost.php** file

One approach could be [writing a plugin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) to be executed before `execute()` method, and validate there if customer is logged in, if email has been used as coupon previously, and then create on the fly a coupon with desired values

Comment: The email should be able to be used unlimited about of times, and a customer is not required to login in order to use their email as a coupon. If a customer unsubscribes from our newsletter, the email should no longer function as a coupon code.